# Is there a tiny but smart pet I can hide in my pocket while traveling?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel

I live in a new country every month.

I want a pet as a companion. It should be as smart as possible for its size so you know it can be my companion.

And it should be something that won't add more suffering and complexity to my life. So it should be something I can hide in my pocket in airports and airplanes.

Does that exist?

Comment: What about legal issues, like how you have to declare animals travelling with you?

Comment: And how much suffering will that add to the very smart pet's life being shut up in your pocket for a 9 hour flight?

Comment: "Hide" in the face of what level of searching?  If you are subjected to a pat-down search, which is a fairly common occurrence at airport security checkpoints, it will be discovered.

Comment: ... or is squashed. Or escapes during the flight, causing panic, or begins to gnaw though the cabling...

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/Scruff-Luvs-Little-Multiple-30321/dp/B09CWJ4K1V/ref=sr_1_4?crid=S96PJHZG9RWA&keywords=scruff+a+luv&qid=1641038236&sprefix=scruff%2Caps%2C412&sr=8-4) would do fine with you.

Comment: I love the triggered responses. Thanks @NeanDerThal that's exactly what I need

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about travel.

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not exist.

There are no real life pets which are smart enough and small enough to travel in a pocket while traveling international and moving countries frequently.
Not many animals, if any at all, will fit the picture. The kind of life you picture for the pet will be hard to very unkind to the pet.
Besides, you will not be able to travel around with a pet in your pocket, planes and most trains will require proper pet carriers if they allow pets at all.

Besides, most animals are not allowed in across borders, only cats and dogs are usual exceptions and those are still bound to many rules.

About 25 years ago they designed a pet for you, a [Tamagotchi.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamagotchi)
Not as intelligent but for the rest it does fit your requirements, at least better than any real life beasts.